# Уведомление о новом сообщение как в контакте

Tags: jquery, ajax, javascript

Здравствуйте. Интересует реализация(хотя бы схематично) уведомлений о новых сообщения, как, к примеру, это сделано в контакте - всплывающее окошко в стороне с сообщением. Можно ли это сделать ручками (самому навертеть ajax) или есть определенные технологии.

Comment: Вы используете конкретную CMS?

Answer (score 2):

Вот, про всплывающие сообщения почитайте тут:

[плагин на jQuery для показа сообщений-подсказок](http://sofcase.net/post/make-plugin-on-jquery-for-shows-hintmessages/)

А что касается схемы прихода сообщений, то это уже зависит как реализована ваша почта.
Можно на ajax сделать обращение с таймером к базе данных со входящими сообщениями. Это  повысит нагрузку на сервер. Уверен есть какие более совершенные схемы для организации такой работы. 
Надеюсь ссылка на всплывающие окна была полезной.
С уважением.

Answer (score 1):

[comet](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%29), [ajax](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/AJAX), [web-socket](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket).

При правильной реализации нагрузка на сервер будет минимальна.

Answer (score 1):

Решение задачи может основываться на требованиях к частоте обновления. Насколько быстро пользователь должен получить уведомление о сообщении? Если нужна информация в реальном времени - это одна задача. Если информацию можно обновлять с погрешностью в 5-10 минут это другая. В чате задержки в 5 минут будут смотреться нелепо, в то время как для почтового уведомления весьма приемлемое время.

Как написал [@lampa](/users/5030/lampa), для обновления в реальном времени хорошо подходят технологии COMET.

К сожалению на практике оказывается, что для высоконагруженной системы затраты весьма ощутимы.

Если задача не стоит получать сообщения моментально и допускается некоторая задержка - можно формировать на сервере статичный файл с информацией раз в 5 минут. А клиент будет запрашивать его каждую минуту аяксом.

Nginx с легкостью раздаст вашу статику на аякс запросы и не будет нагружать сервер и БД. А сервер будет с какой-то периодичностью просто формировать новый файл с новыми данными.

Answer (score 0):

Я вижу два варианта. Отправлять каждую секунду некий AJAX запрос на проверку новых сообщений. Второй вариант более грамотный - использование WebSocket. Если вкратце, то с клиентом устанавливается соединение в виде канала, и при отправке сообщения данному клиенту отправляется оповещение в этот самый канал.